# Send parameters AND data to web server with Swift 3

Tags: ios, http, swift3

I'm trying to figure out how to send a photo from an iPhone to my web server.

I also need to send parameters containing the size of the photo, it's filename and other additional information about the photo in the same request as the parameter data.

The code below is on the right track I think, but where do I put the parameter data called `params`:

```
        let params: Array<String> = [aI.filename, String(aI.size), String(aI.dateTime.year), String(aI.dateTime.month), String(aI.dateTime.day), String(aI.dateTime.hour), String(aI.dateTime.minute), String(aI.dateTime.second), String(aI.dateTime.millisecond)]


        var serverURL = URL(string: "http://192.168.0.23/upload.php");
        var req = NSMutableURLRequest(url: serverURL!, cachePolicy: NSURLRequest.CachePolicy.useProtocolCachePolicy, timeoutInterval: 60.0);
        //Set request to post
        req.httpMethod = "POST";

        //Set content type
        req.setValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type");


        let task = URLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(req){ data, response, error in
            if error != nil{
                print("Error -> \(error)")
                return
            }

            do {
                let result = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: []) as? [String:AnyObject]

                print("Result -> \(result)")

            } catch {
                print("Error -> \(error)")
            }
        }

        task.resume()
        return task
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Allthough some of the answers pushed me in the right direction, they still didn't fit my project and so I continued googling an I managed to find exactly what I needed in the following article: http://swiftdeveloperblog.com/image-upload-example/

I needed to make the HTTP request asynchronously and using sessions,
which I didn't specify in the question because the question was merely about how to send both several parameters along with data in one single request.

It is called `Multipart Form Data` when doing so.

I had to modify the code from the article a little bit to make it work for my application,
so I'm sharing my **Swift 3** code below:

Trigger code

```
let params = [
            "filename"      : chunkOwner.filename                       ,
            "size"          : String(describing: chunkOwner.size)                   ,
            "year"          : String(chunkOwner.dateTime.year)          ,
            "month"         : String(chunkOwner.dateTime.month)         ,
            "day"           : String(chunkOwner.dateTime.day)           ,
            "hour"          : String(chunkOwner.dateTime.hour)          ,
            "minute"        : String(chunkOwner.dateTime.minute)        ,
            "second"        : String(chunkOwner.dateTime.second)        ,
            "millisecond"   : String(chunkOwner.dateTime.millisecond)   ,
        ]

uploadChunk(url: URL(string: "http://192.168.0.23/upload.php")!, data: photoData, params: params)
```

Upload code:

```
func uploadData(url: URL, data: Data!, params: [String: String])
    {
        let cachePolicy = NSURLRequest.CachePolicy.reloadIgnoringLocalCacheData;
        let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: url, cachePolicy: cachePolicy, timeoutInterval: 6.0);
        request.httpMethod = "POST";

        let boundary = generateBoundaryString()

        request.setValue("multipart/form-data; boundary=\(boundary)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")


        if(data == nil)  { return; }

        request.httpBody = createBodyWithParameters(parameters: params, filePathKey: "file", data: data, boundary: boundary)



        //myActivityIndicator.startAnimating();

        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest) {
            data, response, error in

            if error != nil {
                print("error=\(error)")
                return
            }

            // You can print out response object
            print("******* response = \(response)")

            // Print out reponse body
            let responseString = NSString(data: data!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)
            print("****** response data = \(responseString!)")

            do {
                let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: []) as? NSDictionary

                print(json)



            }catch
            {
                //if you recieve an error saying that the data could not be uploaded,
                //make sure that the upload size is set to something higher than the size
                print(error)
            }


        }

        task.resume()

    }


    func createBodyWithParameters(parameters: [String: String]?, filePathKey: String?, data: Data!, boundary: String) -> Data {
        var body = Data();

        if parameters != nil {
            for (key, value) in parameters! {
                body.appendString(string: "--\(boundary)\r\n")
                body.appendString(string: "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"\(key)\"\r\n\r\n")
                body.appendString(string: "\(value)\r\n")
            }
        }

        let mimetype = "text/csv"

        body.appendString(string: "--\(boundary)\r\n")
        body.appendString(string: "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"\(filePathKey!)\"; filename=\"\(parameters!["filename"]!)\"\r\n")
        body.appendString(string: "Content-Type: \(mimetype)\r\n\r\n")


        body.append(data)
        body.appendString(string: "\r\n")

        body.appendString(string: "--\(boundary)--\r\n")

        return body
    }




    func generateBoundaryString() -> String {
        return "Boundary-\(NSUUID().uuidString)"
    }
```

Also include the following code at the bottom of your `.swift` file outside of your class:

```
extension Data {
    mutating func appendString(string: String) {
        append(string.data(using: .utf8)!)
    }
}
```

And for the PHP upload script I did some changes and now looks like this:

```
<?php
    $target_dir = "/var/www/html/uploads";if(!file_exists($target_dir)){
        mkdir($target_dir, 0777, true);
    }

    $target_dir = $target_dir . "/" . basename($_FILES["file"]["name"]);
    echo count("size: ".$_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"]);


    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], $target_dir)){

        echo json_encode([
            "Message" => "The file ". basename( $_FILES["file"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.",
            "Status" => "OK",
        ]);

    } else {

        echo json_encode([
            "Message" => "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.",
            "Status" => "Error",
        ]);

    }
?>
```

**Important Note:**

> Your app will fail to upload data if your server php file called
>   `php.ini` is configured to accept files smaller than the data you're
>   trying to upload.
>
> For example: If `php.ini` is configured to accept 2 MB, then any
>   uploads larger than 2 MB will be ignored and your app will receive a
>   response saying that something went wrong.
>
> To change the file size acceptance in `php.ini` you need to look for
>   the variable called `upload_max_filesize` and `post_max_size`and change those to whatever file size
>   your system requires.

Answer (score 0):

You can put them to [httpBody](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsmutableurlrequest/1409064-httpbody) or to [httpBodyStream](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsmutableurlrequest/1409529-httpbodystream) (by using NSInputStream)

But don't forget to transform params for server protocol (for example xml, json, or binary data with custom format).
For your content type (application/x-www-form-urlencoded), you can find format in [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POST_(HTTP)):

```
 keyName=value&keyName2=value2
```

The keys and values should contain of URLPathAllowedCharacterSet, to achieve it you can use [stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsstring/1411946-stringbyaddingpercentencodingwit?language=objc).
To convert the KeyValue string to NSData, you can use method [dataUsingEncoding](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsstring/1416696-datausingencoding?language=objc).

Answer (score 0):

I am sharing you one way of posting data using `NSURLConnection` in `Swift3`

Your URL

```
 var serverURL = URL(string: "http://192.168.0.23/upload.php")
```

Your parameters to be like this , just discuss with server people to which parameters you to need pass data Then assign your value to that parameter like below

```
serverparameter1 = \(value to post)& serverparameter2 = \(value to post2).......
```

With your params I did like this have a look

```
let params = "filename= \(aI.filename)&size = \(String(aI.size))& dateTimeYear =\(String(aI.dateTime.year))&dateTimeMonth =\(String(aI.dateTime.month))& dateTimeDay =\(String(aI.dateTime.day))&dateTimeHour =\(String(aI.dateTime.hour))&dateTimeMinute =\(String(aI.dateTime.minute))&dateTimeSecond =\(String(aI.dateTime.second))&dateTimeMilliSecond=\(String(aI.dateTime.millisecond))"
```

Convert your Photo Data to Base64String like below

```
var base64String: NSString!
let myImage = UIImage(named:"image.png")
let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(myImage, 0.9)
base64String = imageData!.base64EncodedString(options: NSData.Base64EncodingOptions.endLineWithLineFeed) as NSString!
print(base64String)
```

then pass as stringParameter

```
&ImageDataStr = \(base64String)
```

then final Url seems to be look like

```
 \(serverURL)/\(params)
```

OR

```
 \(serverURL)/Upload?\(params)
```

Step by step request

```
    var serverURL = URL(string: "http://192.168.0.23/upload.php")

    let params = "filename= \(aI.filename)&size = \(String(aI.size))& dateTimeYear =\(String(aI.dateTime.year))&dateTimeMonth =\(String(aI.dateTime.month))& dateTimeDay =\(String(aI.dateTime.day))&dateTimeHour =\(String(aI.dateTime.hour))&dateTimeMinute =\(String(aI.dateTime.minute))&dateTimeSecond =\(String(aI.dateTime.second))&dateTimeMilliSecond=\(String(aI.dateTime.millisecond))&photoDataStr = \(base64String)"

    var status:NSString = "\(serverURL)/Upload?\(params)" as NSString

    status = status.addingPercentEscapes(using: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)! as NSString


    let url = URL(string: status as String)!


    let request = URLRequest(url: url, cachePolicy:NSURLRequest.CachePolicy.reloadIgnoringLocalAndRemoteCacheData, timeoutInterval: 600)
    // need synchronous
```

Here you will get responseData

```
      var response:URLResponse?
      var responseD:Data = try! NSURLConnection.sendSynchronousRequest(request, returning:&response)
```

Finally make that BinaryData to readable

```
    // save to string - the result came from the Server call
    var serverResults:NSString = NSString(data: responseD, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)!

    print(serverResults)
```

For Example your Result

```
if serverResults.range(of: "RESULT&gt;APPROVED").location != NSNotFound
    {
        return "Data posted"
    }
    else
    {
        return "Failed to post"
    }
```

Comment: But where is the photo data? I can see on the Step-by-step that there params are there, but where is the photo data in the final request?
Also, your example is not asynchronous and does not use sessions, which is not recommended anymore by Apple.

Comment: please refer edited.
One way of sending data is -- Convert your Photo Data to Base64String and send it

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I managed to find the information that fit my question perfectly elsewhere, I have shared my conclusion and wrote my own answer.